# How to parse this sentence. What kind of clause of "that you would ask him to pull your beard."?

Tags: sentence-construction

> He bet me $100 **that you would ask him to pull your beard.**

How to parse  this sentence?

What kind of clause of "that you would ask him to pull your beard."?

Answer (score 2):

*To bet* and *to wager* accept a that-clause as complement.

**I bet (that) you cannot jump over this barrel.**

Or an indirect object, a direct object, and a complement:

**I  bet you $100 that you cannot jump over this barrel.**

Comment: if ""that you would ask him to pull your beard" is a complement,whose complement is it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the word "whose".

Comment: I mean in your explanation, you said that "that you would ask him to pull your beard" can be accepted as complement, so which part does this that-clause complement?